# JavaScript Elements of array being equal function not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

While taking some online JS tests, I am stuck on why my function for testing if the elements within two arrays are equal is not working. I am using the function to make sure that the new array does not have duplicate values.

The following is my function for testing if the elements of the arrays are equal or not:

```
  const isEqualArr = (a, b) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] != b[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
```

I call to the function within a for loop, then I test for undefined, because the first time around, the outputArr is empty

```
for (let x = 0; x < numsLength; x++) {
  if (typeof outputArr[x] != 'undefined') {
     if (isEqualArr(tempArr, [outputArr[x]])) {
```

However, the result shows that there are duplicates:

```
0: Array [ -1, 0, 1 ]
​
1: Array [ -1, 2, -1 ]
​
2: Array []
​
3: Array [ -1, -1, 2 ]
​
4: Array []
​
5: Array [ 0, 1, -1 ]
​
6: Array [ 0, -1, 1 ]
​
7: Array [ 1, 0, -1 ]
​
8: Array [ -1, 0, 1 ]
```

The other issue is that not only do I have two null arrays (duplicates), but when I test for null before the push, it is not working either:

```
if(tempArr != null ) {
  outputArr.push(tempArr);
}
```

I have tried tempArr[0] != null, tempArr[0] != '' as well as

```
if (typeof tempArr[0] != 'undefined')
```

But it still inserts null arrays into the outputArr.

The following is the premise of the test:
Given an integer array nums, return all the triplets [nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]] such that i != j, i != k, and j != k, and nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0.

Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets. Given nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]

The following code is my solution, but the duplicate entries, as well as the null entries, makes this an incorrect solution. If you guys can see why my isEqualArr function is at fault, then I would appreciate it.

```
const threeSum = (nums) => {
  let numsLength = nums.length;
  let tempArr = [];
  let outputArr = [];

  if (numsLength > 3) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numsLength; i++) {
      for (let j = 1; j < numsLength; j++) {
        for (let k = 2; k < numsLength; k++) {
          if (
            i != j &&
            i != k &&
            j != k &&
            nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0
          ) {
            tempArr[0] = nums[i];
            tempArr[1] = nums[j];
            tempArr[2] = nums[k];

            for (let x = 0; x < numsLength; x++) {
              if (typeof outputArr[x] != 'undefined') {
                if (!isEqualArr(tempArr, [outputArr[x]])) {
                  if (typeof tempArr[0] != 'undefined') {
                    outputArr.push(tempArr);
                    console.log(
                      'temp: ' + tempArr + ' outputArr: ' + outputArr[x]
                    );
                    console.log(
                      'compare: ' + isEqualArr(tempArr, outputArr[x])
                    );
                    console.log(outputArr);
                    tempArr = [];
                  }
                }
              }
            }

            if (i == 0) {
              outputArr.push(tempArr);
              tempArr = [];
            } else {
              // do nothing
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return outputArr;
};

const isEqualArr = (a, b) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] != b[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

EDIT: I was able to eliminate the null entries by moving the code that checks if it is the first time to run above the for loop:

```
if (i == 0) {
  outputArr.push(tempArr);
  tempArr = [];
} else {
  // do nothing
}

for (let x = 0; x < numsLength; x++) {
  if (typeof outputArr[x] != 'undefined') {
    if (!isEqualArr(tempArr, [outputArr[x]])) {
      if (typeof tempArr[0] != 'undefined') {
        outputArr.push(tempArr);
        console.log(
          'temp: ' + tempArr + ' outputArr: ' + outputArr[x]
        );
        console.log(
          'compare: ' + isEqualArr(tempArr, outputArr[x])
        );
        console.log(outputArr);
        tempArr = [];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, another thing that is not working if the following logic:

```
i != j &&
i != k &&
j != k &&
```

You can see by the outputArr that this logic is being completely ignored.

REFACTORED: even though the online test marked my solution as wrong, you can see with the results, that it is correct. Especially when you factor in the conditionals for making sure that nums[i] != nums[j] and so forth:

```
 const threeSum = (nums) => {
  let numsLength = nums.length;
  let tempArr = [];
  let outputArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numsLength; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numsLength; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < numsLength; k++) {
        if (
          nums[i] != nums[j] &&
          nums[i] != nums[k] &&
          nums[j] != nums[k] &&
          nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0
        ) {
          if (typeof outputArr[0] != 'undefined') {
            /**********
            * if it reaches this conditional
            * then outputArr has at least one element
            ***********/
            if (typeof outputArr[k] != 'undefined') {
              tempArr[0] = nums[i];
              tempArr[1] = nums[j];
              tempArr[2] = nums[k];
              if (isEqualArr(tempArr, outputArr)) {
                // do nothing because there is already an element within the array
              } else {
                outputArr.push(tempArr);
                // empty tempArr after insert
                tempArr = [];
              }
            }
          } else {
            // push triplet elements into temp array for the first iteration only
            tempArr[0] = nums[i];
            tempArr[1] = nums[j];
            tempArr[2] = nums[k];

            // insert tempArr for the first iteration only
            outputArr.push(tempArr);
            // empty tempArr after insert
            tempArr = [];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return outputArr;
};

const isEqualArr = (a, b) => {
  for (elem in b) {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] != elem[i]) {
        // do nothing
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

RESULTS:

```
(3) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) [-1, 0, 1]
1: (3) [1, 0, -1]
2: (3) [-1, 1, 0]
length: 3
```

Comment: What is the input `isEqualArr` receives?

Comment: It receives either true if the elements are equal or false if they are not. If they are not equal elements, then push the tempArr into the outputArr

Comment: *receives*, as in what arguments are passed in. Not what value it *produces*.

Comment: It receives two arrays - tempArr and outputArr

Comment: But what do these arrays contain? Let me put it this way - how do I call the function in order to reproduce what you see? What data should I give it? I've tried `isEqualArr([1, 2, 3,], [1, 2, 3])` and I get `true`, I've tried `isEqualArr([1, 2, 4,], [1, 2, 3])` and I get `false`. So I don't know *what* causes the error you see. *that* is why I'm asking. You've not provided enough information in your question to be able to diagnose the issue. Not without reverse engineering a whole bunch of code and guessing what the input values are for that one, as well.

Comment: Hey @VLAZ, thank you for your questions, but if you use the following value for the nums array - nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4], then when you run the code, you will see it is coming back with two  entries [ -1, 0, 1 ] - once at the beginning and another time at the end of the outputArr. This information is given where you see the premise of the test question

Answer (score 1):

Your inner for loop is confusing, if you replace it by a forEach you can see what's going on, you should pass as argument `outputArr[x]` not `[outputArr[x]]` and there's more stuff.

```js
const threeSum = (nums) => {
  let numsLength = nums.length;
  let tempArr = [];
  let outputArr = [];
  if(numsLength < 3) return;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < numsLength; i++) {
     for (let j = 1; j < numsLength; j++) {
        for (let k = 2; k < numsLength; k++) {
          if (
            i != j &&
            i != k &&
            j != k &&
            nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0
          ) {
            tempArr.push(nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]); // push three at the same time, it's cleaner and avoid problems

            outputArr.forEach((arr, index) => {
               if(!isEqualArr(arr, outputArr[index])) outputArr.push(tempArr); // outputs correctly
            });

            if (i == 0) {
              outputArr.push(tempArr);
              tempArr = [];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  return outputArr;
};

const isEqualArr = (a, b) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] != b[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(threeSum([-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]));
```

Comment: Very good point @testing_22. BTW, I noticed that your logic of i != j, i != k, j != k is not working either - [-1,-1,2] - each of the triplet values have to match the criteria. If you can figure that out, then I will mark your answer correct

Comment: Oh, I think I need to check if num[i] != num[j] and so forth - nope, that was not it

Comment: BTW @testing_22, according to the online test, the expected outcome is [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]] and your solution produces [[-1,0,1],[-1,2,-1],[-1,-1,2]], which is much better than mine, that is for sure

Comment: I'm using your logic and as you put `if numsLength > 3` so I assumed it won't return anything with less or equal than three (which makes no sense for length 3)

Comment: But I changed now so that it works with 3 elements

Comment: I also wanted to thank you for sharing the forEach code, that is so beautiful and you make a good point about the numsLength > 3 - I am trying to remember why I did that in the first place

Comment: It happens, lol. The key is to make the code more clean abstracting low level things so that you can get a better understanding of your work. `forEach` is of course slower than the common `for` loop, but if you aren't worried about time complexity you can of course enjoy its beauty.